# Prime.new is obsolete - how to rewrite this code?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, enumerator

This code finds the first prime number that has 500 divisors. When I run it it work, but I am told that "Prime::new is obsolete. use Prime::instance or class methods of Prime."

I thought this meant that I can replace 'Prime.new' with 'Prime.instance', but when I do that I'm told that 'next is an undefined method'. Since prime should be an enumerator, why am I getting this error? This right answer is 76576500.

```
require 'mathn'

primer  = Prime.new
primes  = [ primer.next ]
seed    = 500
n       = (seed * (seed + 1)) / 2
i       = seed + 1

def count_prime_factors primer, primes, n
  total = 1
  max   = Math.sqrt(n).to_i

  while primes.last < max
    primes << primer.next
  end

  primes.each do |i|
    count = 0
    while n % i == 0
      n = n / i
      count += 1
    end
    if count > 0
      total *= count + 1
    end
  end

  total
end

while(count_prime_factors(primer, primes, n) < seed)
  n += i
  i += 1
end

puts n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `Prime.new` with `Prime.instance` and each instance of `primes.next` with `primes.succ`.

---

See [the source code for the `Prime` class](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/prime.rb). You will find that `Prime.next` is aliased to `Prime.succ` but `Prime.next` has no implementation itself. The behavior changes a bit depending on how you create an instance of `Prime`, which is why you get different errors above.

Answer (score 2):

For now, you should use `Prime::EratosthenesGenerator.new` instead of `Prime.new` (ruby 2.2+)